# Build SDK in Flutter/Dart and use it from Java / Web

Tags: flutter, dart

We are building an application in Flutter, which is composed of an SDK (no UI Code) and a Flutter UI, using the SDK.
We have now the requirement to provide the SDK for other, native target platforms (iOS, Android, Web, JVM) and use it in existing applications. As far as we have understood this is possible for iOS and Android. But is this also possible (or planned) for Web and JVM? We simply want to minimise the effort to build the similar SDK in various platform specific technologies.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can build your Flutter app targeting web https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/faq#is-the-web-version-of-flutter-ready-for-production

If you want to target the Desktop then check https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/desktop to see if it meets your requirements.